# Meteor login through different server

Tags: meteor, react-native

I want to let my meteor users login through my react-native app.

I have one website built by Meteor/reactjs and the other is an App using android react-native and they both share the same Mongo database.
My meteor website uses bcrypt (meteor accounts-password), and my react-native app where I tried to use SHA256 and bcrypt so when I log in through my react-native app which is connected to the database, the hashed passwords do not match and I get an error.

I'm just getting really confused as to how to hash my react-native password to get it to the match the meteor users' hashed password. Any help would be great, cheers.

This is the front end

```
   sendAjax = () => {

   const m = encodeURIComponent(this.state.email);
    const p = encodeURIComponent(this.state.password);
    const hashDigest = sha256(p);
    const requestBody = `email=${m}&password=${hashDigest}&mphone`;
    //POST
    fetch("http://**************/users/auth", {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",  
           "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: requestBody
    }).then(function (res, next) {
        console.log("fetch request ", JSON.stringify(res.ok));
        if(res.ok){
            res.json().then(function (json) {
                console.info(json);
                console.info(json.verifystate);
                if(json.verifystate){
                    Alert.alert("Login success");
                    Actions.leaderBoard();
                }else{
                    Alert.alert("Login fail, please try again");
                }
            });
        }else{
            Alert.alert('Noted','request failed',[{text: 'confirm', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed!')},]);
            next();
        }
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("fetch fail");
        Alert.alert('Noted','system error',[{text: 'confirm', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed!')},]);
    });
   }
```

This is my backend

```
   app.post('/users/auth', function(req, res) {
        loginData(db, req.body.email, req.body.password, function(result){
          if(result == 1){
            console.log("find the result!");
            res.send({"verifystate":true});
          }else{
            console.log('cannot find it');
          }
        });    
   });
  ......
  var loginData = function(db, email, myPlaintextPassword, mphone, callback){
var collectionUser = db.collection('users');
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, salt, function(err, hash) {

       var queryStr = {"emails.address": email, "services.password.bcrypt": hash};
        collectionUser.count(queryStr, function(err, result) {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log('Error2:'+ err);
            }
            callback(result);
        });
    });
});
```

};

Comment: are you using the react-native-meteor package for your react-native app?

Comment: Does your RN app have a back-end? How does it connect to the database? Can you post the code you are using to validate the password? Are you trying to use bcrypt on the client (the RN runtime)?

Comment: Hello, I've updated my post to include frontend and backend code

Comment: I am looking for the same answer as well, because I'm trying to build an app using Nativescript (similar to React Native) and wants it to log in. I haven't implemented it but based on my readings, using JWT may help.